# Adding zeros to integer in child loop?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a loop, and through each loop I would like to add a 0 to the child loop's max range.

Example:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
  for(var n=0;n< [?] ;n++)
```

The child loop should be looping from `0` to `1`,`10`,`100`,`1000` and so on each time around it should add a `0` to the max range. 
Maybe I'm just bad at math idk but how would I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the power of [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  for(var n = 0; n < Math.pow(10, i); n++)
```

Comment: Haha I knew there was something out there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
 for(var n=0;n<Math.pow(10,i);n++)
```